# Bootstrap Cards Running into Each Other

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I need to get 4 Bootstrap cards in a `row`, all the same `width` and `height` and with some space between each.

However, on a Tablet `viewport`, the cards are overlapping

I tried using `col-md-3` so all 4 cards add up to 12 and also added .card `{display:inline-block;}`

```
 <div class="card-group mt-2">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                    <div class="card Python" style="width: 14rem;">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">CSWB 180 - Python</h5>
                                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Python Programming</h6>
                                <a href="#" class="card-link">Read about Course</a>
                            </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                    <div class="card SQL" style="width: 14rem;">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">CSIT 150 - SQL</h5>
                                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Introduction to SQL</h6>
                                <a href="#" class="card-link">Read more about Course</a>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                        <div class="card JavaScript" style="width: 14rem;">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">CSWB 120 - JavaScript</h5>
                                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">JavaScript and jQuery</h6>
                                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Read about Course</a>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                        <div class="card PHP" style="width: 14rem;">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title">CSWB 150 - PHP</h5>
                                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">PHP Programming</h6>
                                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Read about Course</a>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </div>          
        </div>
```

Comment: why do you have `style="width: 14rem;"` on each card

Comment: To give them the same size, or that is what I hope it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the `style="width: 14rem;"` and get what you're looking for

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="card-group mt-2">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
    <div class="card Python">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">CSWB 180 - Python</h5>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Python Programming</h6>
        <a href="#" class="card-link">Read about Course</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
    <div class="card SQL">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">CSIT 150 - SQL</h5>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Introduction to SQL</h6>
        <a href="#" class="card-link">Read more about Course</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
    <div class="card JavaScript">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">CSWB 120 - JavaScript</h5>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">JavaScript and jQuery</h6>
        <a href="#" class="card-link">Read about Course</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
    <div class="card PHP">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">CSWB 150 - PHP</h5>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">PHP Programming</h6>
        <a href="#" class="card-link">Read about Course</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you mind telling me why that style="width: 14rem; was messing things up?

Comment: the bootstrap classes are responsible for changing the width, making sure that the cards do not overlap... but with `style="width: 14rem`, you were overriding the behavior of bootstrap classes... and telling the card to hold width = `14em` at all times... you can thank me by accepting this answer :)

Comment: Thanks! Will do, it says I have to wait 6min more before accepting it

Comment: I'd appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-12">
            <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
                <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">CSWB 180 - Python</h5>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Python Programming</h6>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Read about Course</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-12">
            <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
                <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">CSWB 180 - Python</h5>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Python Programming</h6>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Read about Course</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-12">
            <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
                <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">CSWB 180 - Python</h5>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Python Programming</h6>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Read about Course</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-12">
            <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
                <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">CSWB 180 - Python</h5>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Python Programming</h6>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Read about Course</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You should've wrapped `.card` into `.container > .row > .col-*-*`
Wrap your every card element into `.col-*-*`. It'd be easier to work with

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap card width is automatically covers 100% width and you do not have to apply width to it and for the same height of all card you just need to put css for `height: 100%` to `.card` class and remove `display:inline-block` that you are apply to your `.card` class.

```css
.card {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="card-group mt-2">
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-4">
      <div class="card Python">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">CSWB 180 - Python</h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Python Programming</h6>
          <a href="#" class="card-link">Read about Course</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-4">
      <div class="card SQL">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">CSIT 150 - SQL</h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Introduction to SQL</h6>
          <a href="#" class="card-link">Read more about Course</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-4">
      <div class="card JavaScript">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">CSWB 120 - JavaScript</h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">JavaScript and jQuery</h6>
          <a href="#" class="card-link">Read about Course</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-4">
      <div class="card PHP">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">CSWB 150 - PHP</h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">PHP Programming</h6>
          <a href="#" class="card-link">Read about Course</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-4">
      <div class="card Python">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">CSWB 180 - Python</h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Python Programming</h6>
          <a href="#" class="card-link">Read about Course</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-4">
      <div class="card SQL">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">CSIT 150 - SQL</h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Introduction to SQL</h6>
          <a href="#" class="card-link">Read more about Course</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-4">
      <div class="card JavaScript">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">CSWB 120 - JavaScript</h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">JavaScript and jQuery</h6>
          <a href="#" class="card-link">Read about Course</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-4">
      <div class="card PHP">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">CSWB 150 - PHP</h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">PHP Programming</h6>
          <a href="#" class="card-link">Read about Course</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>          
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

one more thing is that if you want 4 boxes in a row and make them in full width directly then you do not have to provide the col-sm-12 class. bootstrap automatically change the col-md-3 width to 100% for the device-width less then 768px.